# How to fallback to browser's default fetch handling within event.respondWith()?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

Within the service worker my fetch handler looks like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      return response || fetch(event.request); //<-- is this the browser's default fetch handling?
    })
  );
});
```

The method event.respondWith() forces me to handle all requests myself including xhr requests which is not what I like todo. I only want the cached resources to be returned if available and let the browser handle the rest using the browser's default fetch handling.

I have two issues with `fetch(event.request)`:

1. Only when devtools is opened it produces an [error](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823392) while fetching the initial URL which is visible in the address bar `https://test.de/x/#/page`. It happens both on initial install and on every reload:

   > Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode`

   and I don't understand why because I am not setting anything
2. It seems to violate the HTTP protocol because it tries to request a URL with an anchor inside:

   > Console: {"lineNumber":0, "message":"The FetchEvent for
   >   \"https://test.de/x/#/page\" resulted in a network error
   >   response: the promise was rejected.", "message_level":2, "sourceIdentifier":1, "sourceURL":""}`

How does fetch() differ from the browser's default fetch handling and are those differences the cause for those errors?

**Additional information and code:**

My application also leverages the good old appCache in parallel with the service worker (for backwards compatibility). I am not sure if the appcache interferes with the service worker installation on the initial page load. The rest of the code is pretty straight forward:

My index.html at `https://test.de/x/#/page` uses appcache and a base-href:

```
<html manifest="appcache" lang="de">
<head>
   <base href="/x/"/>
</head>
...
```

Service Worker registration within the body script

```
window.addEventListener('load', {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/x/sw.js')
});
```

Install and activate event

```
let MY_CACHE_ID = 'myCache_v1';
let urlsToCache = ['js/main.js'];
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(MY_CACHE_ID)
      .then(function (cache) {        
        return cache.addAll(
          urlsToCache.map(url => new Request(url, 
          {credentials:'include'}))
        )
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  //delete old caches
  let cacheWhitelist = [MY_CACHE_ID];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function (cacheName) {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Was this in firefox 59?  Please tree in firefox 60+.  We had a bug that caused us to use the incorrect Request.cache value sometimes on a FetchEvent.request.

Comment: Seems to be Blink/Chrome, per grepping through browser-engine sources: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/fetch/request.cc#298 & https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/serviceworkers/fetch_respond_with_observer.cc#35. Mathias, it’d be helpful to know if you can you reproduce the problem in Firefox 60+ or Safari Technology Preview. It’d probably also be helpful if you used https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50062084/edit to edit/update the question to add more details — e.g., more of your code

Comment: It would also be nice to know what kind of request the FetchEvent was intercepting.

Comment: It was on chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 or maybe one version earlier. In firefox 59 I get the error "ServiceWorker script at https://test.de/x/sw.js for scope https://test.de/x/ encountered an error during installation.". After updating to firefox 60 I get exactly the same, even after reload and after tab closing.

Comment: Errors 1 and 2 are still happening. There is an ongoing bug ticket for error 1: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823392

Answer (score 3):

`fetch(event.request)` should be really close to the default. (You can get the actual default by not calling `respondWith()` at all. It should mostly not be observable, but is with CSP and some referrer bits.)

Given that, I'm not sure how you're ending up with 1. That should not be possible. Unfortunately, you've not given enough information to debug what is going on.

As for 2, it passes the fragment on to the service worker, but that won't be included in the eventual network request. That matches how Fetch is defined and is done that way to give the service worker a bit of additional context that might be useful sometimes.

Comment: How to implement not calling `respondWith()`? Is it safe to do nothing and return nothing for all URLs not contained in my variable `urlsToCache`?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't invoke `respondWith()` (or `waitUntil()` I think) the request will be fetched over the network.

Comment: How to find the cause for the second error: "The FetchEvent for \"https://test.de/x/#/page\" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected."? Does the service worker know why fetch has failed?

Comment: 2 seems like a result of 1, no?